# How can you escape the @ character in javadoc?

Tags: java, escaping, javadoc

How can I escape the `@` symbol in javadoc? I am trying to use it inside a `{@code}` tag, which is inside `<pre>` tags.

I already tried the html escape `&#64;` sequence, but that didn't work.

Comment: Now it has started displaying fine after I adjusted some of the indentation inside the @{code} block!  This was in Eclipse if it matters.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Use the [`{@literal}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@literal%7D) javadoc tag:

```
/**
 * This is an "at" symbol: {@literal @}
 */
```

The javadoc for this will read:

```
This is an "at" symbol: @
```

Of course, this will work for *any* characters, and is the "officially supported" way of displaying any "special" characters.

It is also the most straighforward - you don't need to know the hex code of the character, *and* you can read what you've typed!

Comment: How do you escape the `}` symbol?

Comment: @ADTC You can't. Why would you want to? `}` has no special meaning in html.

Comment: So I guess you can only split it into two `literal` tags.

Comment: @adtc I thought of splitting it too, but you really only need literal with the HTML-like chars, eg when javadocing `Foo<T>` etc, so if you put @literal just around the bits you need to, rather than entire snippets, it should be not a problem.

Comment: I'm surprised this is accepted and so up-voted. Premise of the question: _inside {@code} tag_. {@literal} just doesn't work inside a {@code} tag.

Comment: What? The 11th of the month, '11 at 11:11? You should have posted this exactly a month earlier. ;-)

Comment: @MCEmperor the java Calendar uses 0-based months, so this would be month #11 there - close enough?

Comment: @Bohemian You [convinced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER) me! ;-)

Comment: Omitting the `{` and just using `@literal @` works inside of a `{@code}` tag.

Comment: How can you go about escaping whole _tags_? I want to do something like `{@literal {@code ...}}` (basically show the text "{@code ...}") which Eclipse (falsely??) interprets as `{@code ...}}`.

Answer (score 69):

Just write it as an HTML entity:

```
&#064;
```

From the document "[javadoc - The Java API Documentation Generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#blockandinlinetags)"

> If you want to start a line with the @ character and not have it be interpreted, use the HTML entity @.

This implies that you can use HTML entities for *any* character that you would need to escape, and indeed you can:

> The text must be written in HTML with HTML entities and HTML tags. You can use whichever version of HTML your browser supports. The standard doclet generates HTML 3.2-compliant code elsewhere (outside of the documentation comments) with the inclusion of cascading style sheets and frames. HTML 4.0 is preferred for generated files because of the frame sets.
>
> For example, entities for the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) should be written as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Similarly, the ampersand (&) should be written as `&amp;`.

Comment: It works better than the literal expression when not followed by a space (when writting annotation for example)

Answer (score 12):

my solution is

```
/**
 * Mapper Test Helper.
 *
 * add the following annotations above the class
 * <pre>{@code
 * // junit5
 * @literal @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
 * // junit4
 * @literal @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 * }</pre>
 */
```

Answer (score 5):

### Fixed in javadoc tool from 15.0.2

This issue now appears to be fixed when using javadoc tool from 15.0.2.

That is, we no longer need to escape the @ character when using javadoc multiline `{@code ... }` block.

There is a JDK bug logged https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8130754 ... which is currently not marked as fixed but it no longer reproduces with javadoc 15.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

You got the general idea, try using the octal representation: `&#064;`

Comment: ``@`` has the codepoint 0x40 in hexadecimal, which is 64 in decimal