# How to write "@" in javadoc?

Tags: javadoc

There is a `@` in my code example in javadoc:

```
 * <pre>
 * public class ArticleService<Article, ArticleDao> {
 *     @Autowired
 *     private ArticleDao articleDao;
 *     protected ArticleDao getDao() { return articleDao; }
 * }
 * </pre>
```

It breaks the javadoc, because the preview looks like:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: already answered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290757/how-can-you-escape-the-character-in-javadoc

Comment: first of al this post is to ambiguous and second of all that's definately not how you write javadoc, I suggest looking at some examples.

Comment: @wrschneider99, this is a duplicated question because we can't search `@` in SO, or google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace @ with `&#064;`:

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`{@literal}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@literal%7D) tag:

```
 * <pre>
 *     {@literal @Autowired}
 *     private ArticleDao articleDao;
 * 
 *     protected ArticleDao getDao()
 *     {
 *         return articleDao;
 *     }
 * </pre>
```

I have just tested this to make sure it works... and it does