# Extracting pairs of words using String.split()

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Given:

```
String input = "one two three four five six seven";
```

Is there a regex that works with [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to grab (up to) two words at a time, such that:

```
String[] pairs = input.split("some regex");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs));
```

results in this:

```
[one two, three four, five six, seven]
```

---

This question is about **the split regex**. It is *not* about "finding a work-around" or other "making it work in another way" solutions.

Comment: Why?  Is this a puzzle or a *real* problem?

Comment: It's a puzzle... but it interested me enough to ask it, because look-behinds must be bounded in length, so it seems like a non-trivial problem.

Comment: Java's look-behind is one of the strangest beast. In .NET, you can freely look-behind for variable length. In PCRE, you can only look-behind for fixed length. In Java, due to bug/feature in implementation of `+` and `*`, you *sometimes* can match variable length pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536915/regex-look-behind-without-obvious-maximum-length-in-java

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Currently (last tested on Java 17) it is possible to do it with `split()`, but in real world don't use this approach since it looks like it is based on bug since look-behind in Java should have obvious maximum length, but this solution uses `\w+` which doesn't respect this limitation and somehow still works - so if it is a bug which will be fixed in later releases this solution will stop working.**

**Instead use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes with regex like `\w+\s+\w+` which aside from being safer also avoids maintenance hell for person who will inherit such code (remember to "*Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live*").**

---

Is this what you are looking for?

<sub>(you can replace `\\w` with `\\S` to include all non-space characters but for this example I will leave `\\w` since it is easier to read regex with `\\w\\s` then `\\S\\s`)</sub>

```
String input = "one two three four five six seven";
String[] pairs = input.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs));
```

output:

```
[one two, three four, five six, seven]
```

---

`\G` is previous match, `(?<!regex)` is negative lookbehind.

In `split` we are trying to

1. find spaces -> `\\s`
2. that are not predicted -> `(?<!negativeLookBehind)`
3. by some word -> `\\w+`
4. with previously matched (space) -> `\\G`
5. before it ->`\\G\\w+`.

Only confusion that I had at start was how would it work for first space since we want that space to be ignored. *Important information is that `\\G` at start matches start of the String `^`*.

So before first iteration regex in negative look-behind will look like `(?<!^\\w+)` and since first space **do** have `^\\w+` before, it can't be match for split. Next space will not have this problem, so it will be matched and informations about it (like its ***position*** in `input` String) will be stored in `\\G` and used later in next negative look-behind.

So for 3rd space regex will check if there is previously matched space `\\G` and word `\\w+` before it. Since result of this test will be positive, negative look-behind wont accept it so this space wont be matched, but 4th space wont have this problem because space before it wont be the same as stored in `\\G` (it will have different position in `input` String).

---

Also if someone would like to separate on lets say every 3rd space you can use this form (based on [@maybeWeCouldStealAVan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284661/maybewecouldstealavan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486384/1393766) which was deleted when I posted this fragment of answer)

```
input.split("(?<=\\G\\w{1,100}\\s\\w{1,100}\\s\\w{1,100})\\s")
```

Instead of 100 you can use some bigger value that will be at least the size of length of longest word in String.

---

I just noticed that we can also use `+` instead of `{1,maxWordLength}` if we want to split with every odd number like every 3rd, 5th, 7th for example

```
String data = "0,0,1,2,4,5,3,4,6,1,3,3,4,5,1,1";
String[] array = data.split("(?<=\\G\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+),");//every 5th comma
```

Comment: You should probably change `\w+` to `\S+` in case the notional "words" aren't in fact words. Also, could you add a detailed description/explanation of why this works? It's a great regex, it would be good to make sure everyone understands it thoroughly too.

Comment: As an incentive, if you add a good explanation within the next hour, I'll throw in a +50 bounty bonus! :) (actually, that's rubbish - I'm awarding the bounty anyway - you deserve it, because I for one learned something)

Comment: @Bohemian Could you check if explanation in my updated answer is sufficient?

Comment: That's a great explanation. You rock!

Comment: I just noticed an important implication: using `\G` at the start of an otherwise unbounded look behind expression makes it considered as bounded. This may be a handy way to squeeze out boundedness from an unboundable expression instead of the ugly `{0,100}` workaround

Comment: @dovnwoter Care to leave a comment? Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: Some people are like that - it's just skill envy. BTW no prize for guessing who the bounty is for (finally!) :)

Comment: @Bohemian then I will not be guessing :)

Comment: During the bounty period, you got 14 upvotes - you'll make 100 soon and score a [gold badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer). Not bad - it pays to advertise! Now it occurs to me that posting a bounty gains more rep than the bounty costs. If you felt like it, you could similarly post a bounty to award [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290757/how-can-you-escape-the-character-in-javadoc/8463481#8463481) - I would really like a gold too :)

Comment: That was lovely, nice alternative to doing the whole thing in regex +1 :)

Answer (score 9):

This will work, but maximum word length needs to be set in advance:

```
String input = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven";
String[] pairs = input.split("(?<=\\G\\S{1,30}\\s\\S{1,30})\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pairs));
```

I like Pshemo's answer better, being shorter and usable on arbitrary word lengths, but this (as @Pshemo pointed out) has the advantage of being adaptable to groups of more than 2 words.

Comment: I/m giving you a +1, but it doesn't answer the question of having arbitrarily long words. At least you got something working though.

Comment: +1 for answer that can be adapted easily to any number of words that should be grouped.

Comment: I've tested both solutions in a similar problem of splitting an array into pairs and it was your regex which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me `(\w+\s*){2}\K\s`
example [here](http://regexr.com?36aqa)

- a required word followed by an optional space `(\w+\s*)`
- repeated two times `{2}`
- ignore previously matched characters `\K`
- the required space  `\s`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
[a-z]+\s[a-z]+
```

**Updated:**

```
([a-z]+\s[a-z]+)|[a-z]+
```

[image]

**Updated:**

```
 String pattern = "([a-z]+\\s[a-z]+)|[a-z]+";
 String input = "one two three four five six seven";

 Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile(pattern);
 String[] results = splitter.split(input);

 for (String pair : results) {
 System.out.println("Output = \"" + pair + "\"");
```

Comment: Will this grab the `seven` not matched with a 2nd word pair?

Comment: This does not answer the question. Your regex matches the target content, but `split()` requires a regex to match the *separators*. Your regex does not work (with `split()`)