# Splitting a QString until nth Comma

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have a QString in a format similar to `QString word = "123,12,1,"This is, a test";` (Extracted from a CSV file). I would like to split it up at each comma, excluding any commas in the string in the last cell. The list would be similar to `{"123", "12", "1", "\"This is, a test\""}`.

The format is a number that has a maximum of 3 digits, then a number with a maximum of 2 digits, then a number with a maximum of 1 digit, followed by a string that can include commas. There should always be 4 QStrings in the list. Here is what I'm trying

```
QString word = "123,12,1,\"This is, a test\"";
QStringList list = word.split( QRegExp( "(\\d+)," ) );
```

I got the code for this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892284/split-only-after-comma-3-times-appear-in-java). This code only saves the 4th QString in the list, the first 3 are blank. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Since your requirements are a bit complicated, I suggest you simply use a loop for string parser. This way it will be much more flexible and readable.

Comment: Added a test below in my post. Also, how does this `QString word = "123,12,1,"This is, a test";` even parse in C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

**Edit** - Here is a little test.

If you don't get the expected result, then you **Can't** use QT's split.
You should parse it in a while loop to populate the list.

```
 QString str      = "\"123,12,1,\"This is, a test\"";
 QStringList list =
      str.split(
         QRegExp("(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[\\S\\s][^\"\\\\]*)*\"|\\d+)|,"),
         QString::SkipEmptyParts
      );
```

Comment: The line I tested it on was this (the first line of the CSV): `1,1,9,"This is a sentence`. `list[0]` is `1`, `list[1]` is `9,"This is a sentence`. So it is skipping either the first or second cell, and putting everything else in list[1]

Comment: @maj0rtom - I've added a test for you. If it works, great. If not, you can't use Qt's split like this.

Comment: It works, but it only saves the string (What should be in `cell[3]`) in `cell[0]`.

Comment: @maj0rtom - Sounds like it won't work. In the regex, 3 separators are defined, only 1 is a real separator. 2 that aren't are contained in an alternation within a capture group. Most langs split()'s will make _captured_ separators a separate list item. Otherwise the sep's are not in the list. So `123,12,1,"This is, a test"` using `(""|\d+)|,` normally split as `['123','12','1','"This is, a test"']. There is no other way to split out a quoted string that may have embedded sep's (unless post processing). If you didn't get a list like that, Qt's split won't work on this.

Answer (score 0):

That regular expression only works with digit. You should use something like

```
QRegExp( "[A-Za-z\\d]+," )
```

Comment: When I use this, list[0], list[1] and list[2] are all blank still.

Answer (score 0):

using [regexp sample](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-regexp.html), it's easy to study the appropriate pattern:

[image]

place the context of "Escaped Pattern" in your QRegExp constructor

Comment: So I tried `QStringList list = word.split( QRegExp( "(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\\".*\\\")" ) );`, but this puts everything into list[0]

Comment: I think you have in list[1],list[2] etc all captured patterns. In list[0] there is the entire match.

Comment: `list[1]`, `list[2]`, `list[3]` are all out of range. I also tried The capturedText( ) way, and that gives me errors. I also tried to use capturedTexts similar to the example here without success: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts

Comment: well, capturedTexts works for me. I never used QString.split with regex, then my comment above could be misleading. Sorry I deleted the prious one where I hinted about capturedTexts