# How to split at every second quotation mark

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, c#-2.0

I have a string that looks like this

```
2,"E2002084700801601390870F"
3,"E2002084700801601390870F"
1,"E2002084700801601390870F"
4,"E2002084700801601390870F"
3,"E2002084700801601390870F"
```

This is one whole string, you can imagine it being on one row.

And I want to split this in the way they stand right now like this

```
2,"E2002084700801601390870F"
```

I cannot change the way it is formatted. So my best bet is to split at every second quotation mark. But I haven't found any good ways to do this. I've tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892392/2914876 But I only get an error about invalid arguements.

Another issue is that this project is running .NET 2.0 so most LINQ functions aren't available.

Thank you.

Comment: does it have a line feed?

Comment: Why not split by comma and then pairwise recombine the fields? What are you doing with the resulting strings?

Comment: Get the index of every 2nd quotation and split there.

Comment: What is the source? If it is a file you may use ReadLines

Comment: If all of your data is fixed width, just use the zero based index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var regEx = new Regex(@"\d+\,"".*?""");
var lines = regex.Matches(txt).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Use foreach instead of LINQ Select on .Net 2

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\d+\,"".*?""");
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(txt))
{
    var curLine = m.Value;
}
```

Comment: You need to change `.*` to `.*?` or `[^"]*` because topic starter mentioned that it is single line.

Comment: `Select` and `ToArray` are not available in .NET 2.0

Comment: added the version for .net 2

Answer (score 1):

I see three possibilities, none of them are particularly exciting.

- As @dvnrrs suggests, if there's no comma where you have line-breaks, you should be in great shape.  Replace `,"` with something novel.  Replace the remaining `"`s with what you need.  Replace the "something novel" with `,"` to restore them.  This is probably the most solid--it solves the problem without much room for bugs.
- Iterate through the string looking for the index of the next `"` from the previous index, and maintain a state machine to decide whether to manipulate it or not.
- Split the string on `"`s and rejoin them in whatever way works the best for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I realize regular expressions will handle this but here's a pure 2.0 way to handle as well. It's much more readable and maintainable in my humble opinion.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string data = @"2,""E2002084700801601390870F""3,""E2002084700801601390870F""1,""E2002084700801601390870F""4,""E2002084700801601390870F""3,""E2002084700801601390870F""";

            var parsedData = ParseData(data);

            foreach (var parsedDatum in parsedData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(parsedDatum);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> ParseData(string data)
        {
            var results = new List<string>();
            var split = data.Split(new [] {'"'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (split.Length % 2 != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Data Formatting Error");
            }

            for (var index = 0; index < split.Length / 2; index += 2)
            {
                results.Add(string.Format(@"""{0}""{1}""", split[index], split[index + 1]));
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```