# How to dynamically split a comma separated string into String arrays splitting on nth comma?

Tags: java, regex

My Java webservice's input is a comma separated list of strings ("ABC1,ABCD2,A1,A234B456,C1").

If my split threshold is 2 then I need to split it as

ABC1,ABCD2
A1,A234B456
C1

If my split threshold is 3 then I need to split it as 
ABC1,ABCD2,A1
A234B456,C1

I'm trying to figure out a Java regex way of doing this. I tried checking out StringUtils API but no luck.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just use string split and to rejoin the elements in the resulting array based on your threshold. While technically a bit slower than writing it completely from scratch, it is a lot more readable and it is still in the same complexity class. As you asked for a regex answer this is a comment, but I recommend doing it this way

Comment: It may be better to loop over the string and have a comma counter instead of using regex, though in theory if you constructed the regex string dynamically it could work.

Comment: Thanks. If my input contains thousands of comma separated strings, would this be an optimal solution? Yes, I tried to construct my regex dynamically but it didnt work for all cases. I checked this stackoverflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892284/split-only-after-comma-3-times-appear-in-java

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Feels a little like an XY problem.

Comment: Yea, don't use regex for this. Using `.split()` and a for-loop will be more maintainable and offer a broader range of solutions (so you change your threshold to any number you want). Any regex will limit your threshold to only a few values.

Comment: @Gnana As I said, using split and then rejoining elements is in the same complexity class as iterating yourself, thus it scales aswell. Id suggest trying it, it is pretty short code

Comment: Summary of other comments: If readability is important to you, then use split. If efficiency is important to you, then manually implement the parser. In either case, regex is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Let me discuss with the team about the regex and non-regex solutions.

Comment: I did some metrics for a comma separated list of 1000 items. Regex is slower than for-loop. I have decided to keep away from Regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
((?:[^,]*,[^,]*|[^,]+){2})(?:,|$)
```

Where number `2` is `threshold - 1`

#### [RegEx Demo1](http://regex101.com/r/pZ7fV1/1)

#### [RegEx Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/pZ7fV1/2)

#### OUTPUT:

When `threshold` is `3`:

```
ABC1,ABCD2,A1
A234B456,C1
```

When `threshold` is `2`:

```
ABC1,ABCD2
A1,A234B456
C1
```

**CODE:**

```
int threshold = 3;
String str = "piid1,piid2,piid3,piid4,piid5";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:[^,]*,[^,]*|[^,]+){" + (threshold-1) + "})(?:,|$)");
Matcher m  = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
piid1,piid2,piid3
piid4,piid5
```

Comment: String list = "piid1,piid2,piid3,piid4,piid5";
String[] listarr = list.split("((?:[^,]*,[^,]*|[^,]+){2})(?:,|$)");

I tried this, it doesn't work

Comment: Also, I tried this in ((?:[^,]*,[^,]*|[^,]+){3})(?:,|$) in regex101. It is not splitting as expected

Comment: No you cannot use this in `String#split` method. You will need to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs to get matches out of it using `matcher.find()`

Comment: @Gnana: I have provided your code also in my answer.

Comment: it works like a charm. Thanks. Let me try to propose regex and non-regex options to my team.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job for threshold **2**

```
(?:,[^,]*){1}(,)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0BCUbbRRf4Cc9Htx)

For a threshold **3** change the `{1}` into `{2}`, so it's always the desired threshold - 1

Answer (score 0):

This one is non-reg code,

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

String temp = "";

for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {                         

    if (threshold > i%threshold) 
        temp = temp + (temp.length() > 0 ? "," : "") + splits[i];

    if (threshold - 1 == i%threshold) {
        result.add(temp);
        temp = "";
    }                                         
}

if (temp != "")  //in the case of threshold == split length 
    result.add(temp); //to add last temp

for (String string : result) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for non-regex

`if (threshold != 0) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int len = listarr.length;
            for(int i = 1; i <= listarr.length; i++) {
                if (i % threshold != 0) {
                    sb.append(listarr[i - 1]);
                    if ( i != len) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.append(listarr[i - 1]);
                    result.add(sb.toString());
                    sb.setLength(0);
                }
            }
            result.add(sb.toString());
            for (String string : result) {
                System.out.println(string);
            }

        }`