# How to split a string by every other separator

Tags: java

There's a string

```
String str = "ggg;ggg;nnn;nnn;aaa;aaa;xxx;xxx;";
```

How do I split it into strings like this
   "ggg;ggg;"
   "nnn;nnn;"
   "aaa;aaa;"
   "xxx;xxx;"
???????

Comment: One approach would be to split it at every separator, and then re-combine the pairs.

Another approach would be to write an explicit finite-state machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

```
    String input = "ggg;ggg;nnn;nnn;aaa;aaa;xxx;xxx;";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]{3});\\1;");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        // m.group(0) is the result
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

Will output

> ggg;ggg;
>
> nnn;nnn;
>
> aaa;aaa;
>
> xxx;xxx;

Comment: That works for the specific pattern of 3 repeating characters followed by a semi-colon but won't work with any similar but slightly divergent patterns such as gg;ggg;n;nnnn; so the applicability of this concise solution for general use is rather limited.

Answer (score 1):

Split and join them.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data = "ggg;ggg;nnn;nnn;aaa;aaa;xxx;xxx;";
        String del = ";";
        int splitSize = 2;

        StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
        for (Iterable<String> iterable : Iterables.partition(Splitter.on(del).split(data), splitSize)) {
            sb.append("\"").append(Joiner.on(del).join(iterable)).append(";\"");
        }
        sb.delete(sb.length()-3, sb.length());
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }
```

**Ref :** [Split a String at every 3rd comma in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892284/split-only-after-comma-3-times-appear-in-java)

Comment: What library you used for Iterables ?

Comment: guava-18.0.jar. Please mark correct and up-vote if I resolved your problem.

Comment: edit your answer please and include link to your answer

Comment: Thanks, but isn't working here. Throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you share your input??

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the you only want to check if the last segment is similar and not every segment that has been read.

If that is not the case then you would probably have to use an `ArrayList` instead of a `Stack`.

I also assumed that each segment has the format `/([a-z])\1\1/`.

If that is not the case either then you should change the if statement with:

`(stack.peek().substring(0,index).equals(temp))`

```
public static Stack<String> splitString(String text, char split) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    int index = text.indexOf(split);
    while (index != -1) {
        String temp = text.substring(0, index);
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            if (stack.peek().charAt(0) == temp.charAt(0)) {
                temp = stack.pop() + split + temp;
            }
        }
        stack.push(temp);
        text = text.substring(index + 1);
        index = text.indexOf(split);
    }
    return stack;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use split with a regex:

```
String data="ggg;ggg;nnn;nnn;aaa;aaa;xxx;xxx;";
String [] array=data.split("(?<=\\G\\S\\S\\S;\\S\\S\\S);");
```

- S: A non-whitespace character
- G: last match/start of string, think of it of a way to skip delimiting if the
  previous string matches current one.
- ?<=:positive look-behind will match semicolon which has string behind it.

Comment: Compiler says "Illegal escape character".

Comment: String data="ggg;ggg;nnn;nnn;aaa;aaa;xxx;xxx;";
  String [] array=data.split("(?<=\\G\\S\\S\\S;\\S\\S\\S);");

Comment: When I copied it from my eclipse it disregarded the first \

Answer (score 0):

Some other answer, that only works given your specific example input.

You see, in your example, there are two similarities:

1. All patterns seem to have exactly three characters
2. All patterns occur exactly twice

In other words: if those two properties are really met for all your input, you *could* avoid splitting - as you know **exactly** what to find in each position of your string.

Of course, following the other answers for "real" splitting are more flexible; but (theoretically), you could just go forward and do a bunch of substring calls in order to directly access all elements.