# Split String Every X String does not work

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a `String`, in which I want to split Every x String.
I want to split every 7 String and it works !
Here is the code and the String.
Here is the `String` :

```
 ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

        String str="br_mgt>eth0>63 br_mgt>ath0>63 br0>br_mgt.100>63 br_data>eth0>63 br_data>ath0>63 br0>br_data.200>63 br_data>eth0>63 br_data>ath0>63 br0>br_data.200>75";

        String[] theString=(str.split("(?<=\\.......)"));
        System.out.println("First One : " + theString[0]);
        System.out.println("Second one : " + theString[1]);
```

Output is :

```
First One : br_mgt>eth0>63 br_mgt>ath0>63 br0>br_mgt.100>63
Second one :  br_data>eth0>63 br_data>ath0>63 br0>br_data.200>63
```

And It is true and what I wanted.
I change the String to :

```
str="br0>br_mgt.333>63 br_mgt>eth0>63 br_mgt>ath0>63";
```

And the output is :

```
First One : br0>br_mgt.333>63
Second one :  br_mgt>eth0>63 br_mgt>ath0>63
```

Why is that?

Comment: Expain what's a string for you? "cause this is a string", do you mean word?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a String at every 3rd comma in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892284/split-a-string-at-every-3rd-comma-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str="br_mgt>eth0>63 br_mgt>ath0>63 br0>br_mgt.100>63 br_data>eth0>63 br_data>ath0>63 br0>br_data.200>63";
    String[] array = str.split("(?<=\\G[^\\>]*\\>[^\\>]*\\>[^\\>]*\\>[^\\>]*\\>[^\\>]*\\>[^\\>]*\\>[^\\>]*)\\s+");
    for(String s : array){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the substring method.

ex.

```
String string1 = "CatDog";
String string2 = string1.substring(0,3); //contains 'Cat'
String string3 = string1.substring(3);   //contains 'Dog'
```

Comment: Edited the question.