# Get word pairs from a sentence

Tags: java

Is there a way to take the following sentence:

"I want this split up into pairs"

and generate the following list using java:

"I want", "want this", "this split", "split up", "up into", "into pairs"

Comment: _Is there a way to take the following_ yes, there is a way :D Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow!  Please tell us what you tried so far and what problem occured.

Comment: First show us what you tried before expecting some help!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485687/extracting-pairs-of-words-using-string-split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, lots of ways
one of these can be:

```
String string = "I want this split up into pairs";
String[] words = string.split(" ");
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < words.length-1; ++i) {
    pairs.add(words[i] + " " + words[i+1]);
}
System.out.println(pairs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic algo

Tokenize or split your sentence

```
 I want this split up into pairs -> I, want, this, split, up, into, pairs
```

Then

```
first = read first word
while(there are more words to read){
    second = read next word
    Print first + " " + second
    first = second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example is as follows:

```
    String text = "I want this split up into pairs";
    String[] words = text.split(" ");

    //Print 2 combined words
    for(int i=1;i<words.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", words[i-1],words[i]);
    }
```

Output in Console:

```
I want
want this
this split
split up
up into
into pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a huge java person, so not sure if this code is 100% but it's a general idea for one option.

```
    String x = "I want this split up into pairs";
    String[] parts = x.split(" ");
    List<String> newParts = new ArrayList<String>();;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length()-1; i++) {
        newParts.add(parts[i]+parts[i+1]);
    }
```

Then, the newParts List will have all your pairs