# Java. How can I split a string with multiple spaces on every nth space?

Tags: java, string

Here's a sample string which I intend to split into an array:

```
Hello My Name Is The Mighty Llama
```

The output should be:

```
Hello My
Name Is
The Mighty
Llama
```

The below splits on every space, how can I split on every other space?

```
String[] stringArray = string.split("\\s");
```

Comment: Why not just split it and get the alternate index from the resulting array ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do:

```
String[] stringArray = string.split("(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s");
```

Comment: I would use `\S+` instead of `\w+`.

Comment: I can verify that this works.

Comment: Me too. Awesome job. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

While this is possible to use split to solve it like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486373/1393766) I strongly suggest using more readable way with `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. Here is one of examples to solve it:

```
String string="Hello My Name Is The Mighty Llama";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+(\\s\\S+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output:

```
Hello My
Name Is
The Mighty
Llama
```