# Java. Splitting a multiple word string into two word strings every space

Tags: java, regex

The first round of this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429277/java-how-can-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-spaces-on-every-nth-space/20429737?noredirect=1#20429737) last night. The solution that @Reimeus gave was great and gives the below output from:

```
My name is the mighty llama
```

To:

```
String[] stringArray = string.split("(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s");

My name 
is the
mighty llama
```

However, I now find myself need to correct what I'm doing. I actually need to be able to split the string like so.

```
My name
name is
is the
the mighty
mighty llama
```

Comment: Could you not split it into single words and build your required array in the code?

Comment: Have you tried anything or are you outsourcing your work to SO?

Comment: @Szymon I could, in fact I did. However because I'm doing this for around 1000 articles within a ten minute window I wanted to avoid looping through the articles. As I'm not familiar with Regex i'm asking you guys.

Comment: Regex is not magic either and it also takes time to process it. The problem with splitting is that you would have to go back to an already split off part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot duplicate a token with `String.split()`, because regex is used to SEARCH.

you cannot do this without some kind of edit, maybe a `String.replaceAll()` will accomplish.

Comment: Excellent thanks. In the end I went with removing the first word from the whole string and splitting again as above.

Answer (score 5):

You can split it into single words and build your required array in the code.

```
String string = "My name is the mighty llama";
String[] stringArray = string.split(" ");
String[] outputArray = new String[stringArray.length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length - 1; i++) {
    outputArray[i] = stringArray[i] + " " + stringArray[i+1];
}
```