# Java split on second space

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to no avail, to split a sentence on every second space.

So given, this sentance:

> you're a sausage bap

I have a working example of a single space split:

```
message.split("\\s+")
```

which gives me:

> your
>
> a
>
> sausage
>
> bap

but I need

> your a
>
> sausage bap

I've tried:

```
message.split("\\S+(\\s\\S+)?")
```

as per: [Java. How can I split a string with multiple spaces on every nth space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429277/java-how-can-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-spaces-on-every-nth-space)

which doesn't work for me.

Comment: I would implement it myself, without using regexes or the built-in `split()` method. :)

Comment: Output and input looks same.. Provide the expected input and output

Comment: The question you cite shows two different approaches. One of them uses `String.split()` the other one `Pattern.compile()` to consume a regex. You mixed them up. You can't use this regex with `split()`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
message.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)\\s")
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realise that the other answers I saw in other questions, once copied across added extra backslashes