# Cannot convert Array to List of String correctly

Tags: java, string

There is string with fixed length and it has to be spitted by 15 characters each record. The results should be placed in `List`, however it seems like whole string always placed in 0 position in List.

```
Arrays.asList(a1.substring(1,324).split("[a-zA-Z]{20}"))
```

Why is that?

UPDATE:

```
List<String> l =  Arrays.asList("1111111111     1119999999                                                                                              ".split("[0-9]{15}"));
```

Comment: Please give us sample input/output. No one wants to guess.

Comment: What do you think `split("[a-zA-Z]{20}")` does?

Comment: Should it be `split("\.{20}")`?

Comment: I am not saying you should change it, I am asking what do you think it does (what results do you think you should get)? Also which part it its documentation makes you think that such results should be expected?

Comment: @Pshemo, it splits string if it finds consecutive 20 characters in set [a-zA-Z]. White spaces won't match. Right?

Comment: Yes, it splits string ***on*** 20 consecutive characters in set [a-zA-Z]. Now what results you think you should get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split regex should be :

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\G.{20})");
```

The above split str for every 20 chars

For example below code splits str for every 15 chars:

```
 String str ="hkdhadhkshdkhskhdkashdkasgi2oyeihsadkahdkashdlkhas";
             List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split("(?<=\\G.{15})"));
            System.out.println(list);
```

prints:

```
[hkdhadhkshdkhsk, hdkashdkasgi2oy, eihsadkahdkashd, lkhas]
```

Comment: Nice and succinct! I am not really understand this part `?<=\\G`.

Comment: +1 Nice split regex. There are not many who know this needs `\G`, or even what `\G` does.

Comment: @RCola `\G` represents end of previous match, or if there is no previous match (in case where we are looking for first match) it represents start of the String (is equivalent of `^`).

Comment: Thanks @Phesmo for the explanation, in addition,as per my understanding  `?<=\\G` means lookbehind at the end of previous match and `?<=\\G.{15}` means look behind at the end of previous match after 15 characters, the end of last match is where the split needs to be done.

Comment: @pshemo this reminds me of [your stellar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16486373/256196), which was how I learned about `\G`. It is still my favourite answer on the site - it changed my life :)

Comment: In other words it means , match an empty string from the end of previous match after 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

> There is string with fixed length and it has to be spitted by 15 characters each record. The results should be placed in `List`.

`String.split()` isn't really suitable for something like this. It's designed to split on a delimiter, which "every 15 characters" is not.

You're looking for the functionality in `String.substring()`, which returns a `String` that is the sequence between `[beginIndex, endIndex)`.

With this method:

```
public static List<String> splitByIndex(String toSplit, int index) { 
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < toSplit.length(); i += index) { 
        if (i + index < toSplit.length()) {
            result.add(toSplit.substring(i, i + index));
        } else {
            result.add(toSplit.substring(i, toSplit.length() - 1));
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

You can split a `String` into a `List<String>` by a given number of characters. This example code:

```
String a1 = "I'm the fixed length string that needs to be split by 15 characters.";
List<String> list = splitByIndex(a1, 15);
System.out.println(list);
```

will output:

```
[I'm the fixed l, ength string th, at needs to be , split by 15 cha, racters]
```

---