# how to split from second space found?

Tags: java, split

Ok this is what I have in real life:

```
array = inputText.split("\n");

        for (String each : array) {

            listOfArray.add(each.split(" "));

        }
```

Explanation: i have got an input text box on a xhtml page. This box will contain a few rows. Each row is like:

```
Name1 Surname1 Age1 Sex1 
Name2 Surname2 Age2 Sex2
Name3 Surname3 Age3 Sex3
```

Then I create an array, whose fields will contain each row.
Then I want to create a list of array, whose fields will contain each field of first array. But i want that "Name1 Surname1" is a singular field.

Comment: Just concatenate again your array[0] + " " +array[1]

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA this is just a simple example. I want an implementation that fits every general case of this kind.
yet, the command split will do the array for me. I do not create any array.

Comment: I think my solution fits every use case :). Give me a counterexample

Comment: You've edited your comment, what command? Can you put more details please?

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA is there a way to use the command split(String,index) to do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for solution for this specific case where you don't want to split on first space then you can use:

```
String line = "Name1 Surname1 Age1 Sex1";
String[] arr = line.split("(?<=\\s\\S{1,100})\\s");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output: `[Name1 Surname1, Age1, Sex1]`

`split("(?<=\\s\\S{1,100})\\s")` splits on space which has space and 1-100 non-whitespace characters before it. So since first space doesn't have any space before, it will be skipped in splitting process.
Also I used `{1,100}` instead of `+` because in Java look-behind needs to have obvious maximal length so we can't use `+` there (at least theoretically since there are bugs which allows it like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486373/1393766).

Comment: I think that is what he searched for.

Comment: this code line seems to be the one for me.. and i've got it through. I'm going to implement it and see if it works.

Comment: though it gives me an error on the "?" which is 'dangling near index "0" '

Comment: @Marco It looks like you tried to split like `split("?")`. `?` is regex metacharacter representing `{0,1}` quantifier, but that quantifier doesn't make sense without element which it should describe like `ax?` can match `a` and `ax`. If you want to turn off its special meaning escape it with ``\`` (in string literals you need to also escape it so you need to write it like `split("\\?")`).

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution than @creativecreator's would be:

```
String[] array = start.split(" ");
String[] finalArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
finalArray[0] = array[0] + " " + finalArray[0];
```

i.e. avoiding having to do all of the assignment explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Jon Snow 26 NightsWatch"
String[] values = str.split(" ");
String[] finalValues = new String[3];
for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++)
    if(j == 2)
    {
        index++;
        finalValues[index] = values[j];
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        finalValues[index] += values[j] + " ";
    }
```

P.S. : This code is to show OP just an idea how to proceed. Bugs are not fixed and left for readers to fix.

Comment: This is basically the same I said and I think the version of @AndyTurner is probably better