# Javadoc - multiline comment with annotation (@ sign)

Tags: annotations, javadoc

Based on the answer: [Multiple line code example in Javadoc comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541920/multiple-line-code-example-in-javadoc-comment) I'd like to write following javadoc (on class level).

```
/**
 * Whatever txt1 ...
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *  @Lob
 *  private byte[] foo;
 * }
 * </pre>
 * Whatever txt2 ...
 * 
 * @author $Author: $
 */
public class Foo {
```

However it renders like this (in eclipse preview):

```
Whatever txt1 ...


Author:
 $Author: $
@Lob
private byte[] foo;
 }

Whatever txt2 ...
```

**Please note the messed up order of the author annotation**

Any idea what is the appropriate format/how to properly escate `@` sign?

As once going for:

```
/**
 * Whatever txt1 ...
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *  Lob
 *  private byte[] foo;
 * }
 * </pre>
 * Whatever txt2 ...
 * 
 * @author $Author: $
 */
public class Foo {
```

it's rendered correctly:

```
Whatever txt1 ...

Lob
 private byte[] foo;

 Whatever txt2 ...
 Author:
 $Author: $
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple line code example in Javadoc comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541920/multiple-line-code-example-in-javadoc-comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found answer elsewhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290757/how-can-you-escape-the-character-in-javadoc

the thing is to go for `{@literal @}`

So then:

```
/**
 * Whatever txt1 ...
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 *  {@literal @}Lob
 *  private byte[] foo;
 * }
 * </pre>
 * Whatever txt2 ...
 * 
 * @author $Author: $
 */
public class Foo {
```

renders correctly to:

```
Whatever txt1 ...


{@Lob
private byte[] foo;
}

Whatever txt2 ...
Author:
$Author: $
```

Answer (score 1):

because you refer to the multiline - code example - thread:
The following answer in this thread has your example - escaping the "@" sign on "@Override"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13512524

Regards
Christoph

Comment: If this is in fact a duplicate, you should just mark it as such instead of posting that as an answer.