# Javadoc in JDK 8 : Invalid "self-closing element not allowed"

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

What are the best workarounds when running javadoc using JDK 8 and one receives this error.

It seems that for JDK 8 it has been decided that tags like `<br />` and `<p />` should generate errors, because they are invalid (strict) HTML 4. [see discussion JDK mailing list here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-July/019261.html)

I wonder, because I just wanted to compile some java project using maven and tripped over this issue. Of course, I can file a ticket with the project (and I guess I will), but it would be great if there is a way how to disable this behaviour (for a machine). Otherwise, I expect that a lot of projects need to be fixed before they can be built on JDK 8 without issues.

Comment: Does -Xdoclint:none work?

Comment: Googling for this option yielded a very nice link: http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDK8 and Javadoc has become very strict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528767/jdk8-and-javadoc-has-become-very-strict)

Comment: The causes in the linked article are different ones than the cause that triggered this questions.

Comment: Related. Getting the same error types from maven: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete

Comment: Note that, at least for one project I'm compiling, the following works: `mvn clean package -Dadditionalparam=-Xdoclint:none`

Comment: yes. however this requires JDK8. If you need to make this work for both you need to detect the JDK version first.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For those two particular cases, I think the recommended action is to substitute them with `<p>`. [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format) is the link to the Oracle documentation.

Comment: Best recommendation is from @JE42 to set `-Xdoclint:none.` using this http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

Answer (score 24):

To remove the errors in the **javaDocs** just replace:

- `<p/>` with just `<p>`
- `<br/>` with just `<br>`

Everything works fine after the correction in a excepted way.

Comment: Simple replacement of <p/>with <p> will lead to a number of empty p tag warnings. Up-voted because this was better than the other answers, but I still added a more complete solution as an answer.

Comment: "excepted way" is a funnily precise wording. It's utterly wrong to have the opening tag without the closing one, but it works.

Answer (score 13):

Taken from "[What's New in JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html)" from oracle.com:

> The javac tool now has support for checking the content of javadoc comments for issues that could lead to various problems, such as invalid HTML or accessibility issues, in the files that are generated when javadoc is run. The feature is enabled by the new -Xdoclint option. For more details, see the output from running "javac -X". This feature is also available in the javadoc tool, and is enabled there by default.

Now I did what it told me to do. On JDK 7, the output of "javac -X" does not mention the -Xdoclint option. However, on JDK 8, it gives:

```
 -Xdoclint:(all|none|[-]<group>)[/<access>]
    Enable or disable specific checks for problems in javadoc comments,
    where <group> is one of accessibility, html, missing, reference, or syntax,
    and <access> is one of public, protected, package, or private.
```

So, run the Javadoc utility as follows:

```
javadoc.exe -Xdoclint:none <other options...>
```

In my script, the error you mentioned disappeared by using this option.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, javdoc of JDK 7 will fail with this option, that means you have to detect support for the new option. In the end, I ended up fixing the html.

Comment: If the project is using maven you can use profiles that activate only for jdk8. It's probably better to just fix the HTML if you can and file a bug with the project.

Answer (score 7):

While it is possible to disable error checking with the -Xdoclint option it doesn't repair the problem, it just hides the problem. To make valid HTML4 documents the following substitutions are correct.

- Replace self closing br tags with regular br tags (<br /> with <br>)
- Replace empty p tags with br tags (<p /> with <br>)
- Ensure all p tags have content and are closed (<p>... with  <p> ...</p>)