# Why can't I use the <abbr> tag in my JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I am trying to use the Java 8 javadoc tool but it is complaining that `abbr` is an unknown tag:

`error: unknown tag: abbr`

But as far as I can tell it is a valid tag in [HTML 4.01 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-ABBR) and [HTML 5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-abbr-element).

I see there are [ways to disable the doclint](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html), but I really want to know what list of tags are supported (or why this one is not).

More information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886209/maven-is-not-working-in-java-8-when-javadoc-tags-are-incomplete), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528767/how-to-work-around-the-stricter-java-8-javadoc-when-using-maven) and from [this blog post](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048806), which is fixed in JDK 9.

According to the changelog, the following tags are **missing** in JDK 8:

- abbr
- acronym
- address
- del
- ins
- kbd
- q
- s
- samp
- strike

You will need to disable the HTML lint in JDK 8 if you must use one of these tags.