# XML tag in comment causes ant build error

Tags: java, xml, ant, tags

My team (of 2) is migrating to using ANT to standardize doing our builds.  In Eclipse, when I tried to do the "run as -> ANT Build", these two errors popped up (one each for the opening/closing tag):

```
[javadoc] C:\..\CheckClients.java:31: error: unknown tag: Msg
[javadoc]  //char szLPVHB[]="<Msg>HELLO</Msg>" ;
[javadoc]                    ^
[javadoc] C:\..\CheckClients.java:31: error: unknown tag: Msg
[javadoc]  //char szLPVHB[]="<Msg>HELLO</Msg>" ;
```

You'll also note, that the tag is in a comment; as well that the comment is just informational as a reference to some C++ code that is being re-written into JAVA.

These appear to be the only errors holding up a successful build, as everything else seems to parse just fine, as opposed to what I've seen before reaching this point.  It isn't even the kind of error that causes red text to appear except at the end when I get "Build Failed". I don't see similar questions with regard to XML tags and ANT builds; what's going on?

Comment: It's not Ant but javadoc that's failing here. This might help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528767/how-to-work-around-the-stricter-java-8-javadoc-when-using-maven

Comment: @CAustin So, it appears when the comment was written, it was started with /** as opposed to /*, removing the second asterisk was it.  Thanks.