# jaxb - unmarshalling `>` character problem with javadoc

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, javadoc

I'm using

```
<cxf-version>3.4.4</cxf-version>
<springframework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
<slf.version>1.7.9</slf.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

then in java:

```
final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

but then there is an error while `An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:`

```
[ERROR] /builds/provisioning/target/generated-sources/cxf/at/ActionType.java:26: error: bad use of '>'
[ERROR]  * &lt;complexType name="actionType">
```

it seems like `<` is correctly escaped into `&lt;` but `>` is not escaped and goes as `>` which causes error for me. I found `jaxbUnmarshaller.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");` but it change nothing in this example.

Comment: I think this is "just" a problem with the stricter rules of Java 8+ JavaDoc. See [this SO question for discussions of the issue and potential workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528767/how-to-work-around-the-stricter-java-8-javadoc-when-using-maven).

Comment: Note that unicode and encoding `<` to `&lt;` are 2 different things. Unicode is about `character <-> byte` conversions, the other is `character <-> html entity` conversion.

Comment: Escaping XML characters does not have anything to do with character encoding, so trying to set the character encoding (by setting the property `jaxb.encoding`) is not going to change anything with regard to this issue.

Comment: thanks guys, indeed it works with `<additionalparam>Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>` however it seems to be more like workaround than proper solution. I'll try to play with it some more time. @Edit on website linked by @JoachimSauer there is a comment about `jaxb`, I think it's worth to keep in mind - I tried to use the newest version of `cxf` and `jaxb` but still failing so it seems much more resilient to not generate it for code which I can't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to fix instead of using `<additionalparam>Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>`.
I used all newest versions of `cfx` and `jaxb` in `pom.xml` and worked (generated `&lt` and `&gr` instead of `<` and `>`) so seems it was fixed in `jaxb` lib.

(It didn't work for me earlier because of versions of these in poms and parent pom)